# React Native 0.18.1 use custom font on all views

Tags: javascript, fonts, react-native

I just upgraded to RN 0.18.1 and the way I used to work with custom fonts in my app doesn't work any more. Is there any workaround ?

I used to do this :

```
import React, {AppRegistry, Component, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput} from 'react-native';

var OldText = Text;

class NewText extends OldText {
  defaultProps = {
    customFont: false
  };

  render() {
    var props = _.clone(this.props);

    if (this.props.customFont) {
      return super.render();
    }

    if (_.isArray(this.props.style)){
      props.style.push({fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular'});
    } else if (props.style) {
      props.style = [props.style, {fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular'}];
    } else {
      props.style = {fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular'};
    }

    this.props = props;

    return super.render();
  }
};

React.Text = NewText;
```

Now on this last line `React.Text = NewText`, I get the error: "Attempted to assign to readonly property". Any thoughts on how to use custom fonts now ?

Comment: You could export NewText and use <NewText> instead of <Text> throughout your render methods, but that's not quite as neat as what you were doing.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought but I was wondering if there was any other way a bit "cleaner". I think the way to do it would be to add the font to the style of each Text tag but that would be take some time.

Comment: The 'reusable components' docs suggest subclassing to achieve this, i.e. using the <NewText> component throughout. I've made Text components for each of the styles of font used in the app (TextHeader, TextInfo etc)

Comment: Ok thanks Ben Clayton. I'll do this then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ben Clayton for this answer.
The correct way to do this now is to create a new component (NewText) for example, which is a subclass of React.Text and use it instead of  throughout the app.

My NewText looks like this :

```
'use strict';

import React, {Text} from 'react-native';

import _ from 'lodash';

class NewText extends Text {
  defaultProps = {
    customFont: false
  };

  render() {
    var props = _.clone(this.props);

    if (this.props.customFont) {
      return super.render();
    }

    if (_.isArray(this.props.style)){
      props.style.push({fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular'});
    } else if (props.style) {
      props.style = [props.style, {fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular'}];
    } else {
      props.style = {fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular'};
    }

    this.props = props;

    return super.render();
  }
};

export default NewText;
```